# How can I use a callback in php

Tags: php, callback

Is it possible to execute the callback function only when a condition met inside the caller function?

As example I want to achieve this:

```
function DoThings( callback_func) {
   if( condition is true)
      execute callback_func;
   else
      return 0;
}

function callback_func() {
   echo 'condition met';
}
```

**Note:** I can not move the condition to `callback_func` due it can be from another source, and it's implementation is subject to change frequently.

Comment: please ask whatever question lead you to ask this question - the answer to the asked question is "yes"

Comment: @AD7six I already did, I need to execute the callback function only when condition is true.

Comment: `callback_func()` executes a function, what's the problem?

Comment: @HAßdøµ See here https://3v4l.org/66QhK

Comment: @HAßdøµ Or you can also use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: @vivek_23 That exactly what I need, it looks I had wrong understanding about them, previously I treated them as execute immediately after they passed. Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @HAßdøµ if you look at my answer, $callback() and  call_user_func do exactly the same thing, so both will work

Comment: @MarkOverton Sorry, I had a quick look at it in first, than I saw some examples here running.

Comment: The question appears to be "How can I use a callback in php" (because that's what the answers/comments demonstrate, that you say have helped) - it is not the question you've asked.

Comment: @AD7six ok, tittle changed.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question right and you want to replace 'execute callback_func' with the actual code to execute the function, then the below code should be your answer.

```
function DoThings($callback) {
  if( condition is true)
    $callback();
  else
    return 0;
}

function callback_func() {
  echo 'condition met';
}
```

Comment: How to pass arguments to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable functions : https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

In your example it will be :

```
function DoThings( $callback_func_name) {
   if( $condition)
      $callback_func_name();
   else
      return 0;
}
```